# How to schedule run of Python script and save data onto MongoDB even when computer is off?

Tags: python, mongodb, api, server, apscheduler

I have a locally-hosted MongoDB (port 27017) and I have a python script that fecthes data from an API and stores it in the database.

I want to be able to run the script every day even when my computer is off.

How should I go about making this happen?

I've thought about using the `apscheduler` python package, but I'm not sure if that's enough to store the data in the locally-hosted mongoDB.

I'm also using `pymongo`to manage the databases.

Comment: if MongoDB is on computer which is off then it can't run.

Comment: on LInux I would use system `cron` to run code on selected time or use parameter `@reboot` to run code when computer starts.

Comment: I am using macOS, but I can also use cron with the apscheduler package. The only problem is recording data onto mongoDB. If I have a mongoDB database in the cloud, would it be possible?